# Sort table with empty cell

Tags: javascript

How I want to make the empty cell will be on the top during asc order and at bottom during desc order. Here is my code

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("mytable");
  switching = true;

  dir = "asc"; 

  while (switching) {
     //start by saying: no switching is done:
     switching = false;
     rows = table.rows;

     for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
        shouldSwitch = false;
        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[n];
        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[n];

        if (dir == "asc") {
           if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
           }
        } else if (dir == "desc") {
           if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
              shouldSwitch = true;
              break;
           }
      }
    }
  if (shouldSwitch) {
     rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
     switching = true;
     switchcount ++;
  } else {
    if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
       dir = "desc";
       switching = true;
     }
  }
}
}
```

I had following the tuturial from this website

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp

But the result is like this

if ascending order

```
a
<empty>
<empty>
<empty>
z
```

if descending order

```
z
<empty>
<empty>
<empty>
a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this script with this. it will work for you.

you are pass the parameter `x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[n];` instead of `x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]`;

so that why HTMl domElement can't find that td element.

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");

  switching = true;

  dir = "asc"; 

  while (switching) {
     //start by saying: no switching is done:
     switching = false;
     rows = table.rows;

     for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
        shouldSwitch = false;
        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

        if (dir == "asc") {
           if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
           }
        } else if (dir == "desc") {
           if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
              shouldSwitch = true;
              break;
           }
      }
    }


  if (shouldSwitch) {
     rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
     switching = true;
     switchcount ++;
  } else {
    if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
       dir = "desc";
       switching = true;
     }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: _Just replace this script with this_ Won't help future visitors. Please add information to your answer about the changes you did and why you did it. So the OP can learn and future visitors too.

Comment: @weegee Thanks for your Guidance. it really help me.

Comment: I need it to make the parameter n as it will be implemented on different column

Comment: But why, there is some of the empty cell still in between the non-empty cell? how to prevent this?

Comment: @daffodil can you explain in brief?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the value of `x` when empty depending on the sorting, for example x:

```
if(x == null && dir=='asc'){
   x = 'a';
}else if(x == null && dir=='desc'){
   x = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';
}
```

depending on the type of data your table contains

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a library to implement the functionality, in this case I will recommend [Bootstrap Table](https://bootstrap-table.com/)

I'll leave you a functional example based on the [W3Schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>


<table data-toggle="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
            <th data-field="country" data-sortable="true">Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Sweden</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>France</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Z</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

[Bootstrap Table documentation](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: thanks @Juan Daniel Ornella, somehow the result is same as my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the value of x and y when they empty depending on the sorting with the same value, for example:

```
if(x == null && dir=='asc'){
   x = 'a';
}else if(x == null && dir=='desc'){
   x = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';
}
if(y == null && dir=='asc'){
   y = 'a';
}else if(y == null && dir=='desc'){
   y = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';
}
```

if you only transform one, you will run an infinit loop